# Convert .ISO to .IMG in terminal (Mac) (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, macintosh, iso, flash-memory

I am trying to make a bootable flash drive with Linux on it for my Mac. I have Ubuntu desktop downloaded, and it is in my downloads. The instructions on the Ubuntu website tell me I need to convert the ISO to IMG (of course, because its a Mac, and I cannot boot otherwise, so converting is necessary). This is the terminal command they tell me to run:

`hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso`

I understand I need to replace both paths, and I know I need to change the ubuntu.iso path to the file located in my downloads, but what path do I put in the place of `~/path/to/target.img`? Can someone give a specific example? I tried putting `~/Users/Gurpreet/Desktop/target.img`, but it says no such file or directory. I understand that there is not a file named target.img on my desktop. What path do I use? Specific example and help will get 10 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde expands to `"$HOME"`, so when you write `~/Users/Gurpreet/Desktop/target.img` what you've really written is /Users/Gurpreet/Users/Gurpreet/Desktop/target.img. Just get rid of the redundancy and write one (the tilde) or the other (`/Users/Gurpreet`).